Preloading an NVME SSD for laptop with damaged keyboard
I have an older ASUS QU524 laptop running Windows 10 as a Jellyfin movie server across my network. The keyboard is damaged, and external keyboards do not engage until the BIOS/Setup prompt has passed.
How can I prepare the laptop's internal NVME (or another I have on hand) with Linux Mint preinstalled so that the laptop will boot into Linux? (The reason is that I can't alter the BIOS setup to load a USB drive).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

USB keyboards should generally work just fine in the pre-boot environments. Bluetooth wireless keyboards will have problems, but any keyboard that uses a USB dongle or cable should be fine. It sounds as though your computer has more problems that need addressed.
